# Having trouble writing out avro as array of bytes and then reading it back

Tags: java, serialization, schema, avro

I am just getting started with Avro, and am running into a problem generating test data 
for a process that wants to read that data as a series of bytes.

When I look at the series of bytes that I am writing out it seems like my first field, which is 
an integer is getting mangled. The bytes for the 2nd and third fields seem OK.

Let's say this is my avro schema

```
{
     "type": "record",
     "namespace": "com.foo",
     "name": "test",
     "version": "1",
     "fields": [
        {"name" : "code", "type" : "int", "default" : 1},
        { "name": "firstName", "type": "string", "doc": "firstName" },
        { "name": "lastName", "type": "string", "doc": "lastName" }
     ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
Schema avroSchema =
    SchemaBuilder.record("test").namespace("com.foo").
        fields().
            requiredInt("code").
            requiredString("firstName").
            requiredString("lastName").endRecord();
GenericRecord avroMessage = new GenericData.Record(avroSchema);
avroMessage.put("code", 7);
avroMessage.put("firstName", "robert");
avroMessage.put("lastName", "wong");

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(baos, null);
DatumWriter<Object> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(avroSchema);
datumWriter.write(avroMessage, encoder);
encoder.flush();
baos.close();
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

Integer  code = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getInt();
System.out.println("code:" + code);


// Result is  code:235696751  -- not code:7 as expected.
```

Any idea what I might be doing that is corrupting the first integer field ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the root of the problem.

Initially, I was reading the first byte of the written avro record as an Int, but 
not writing this Int out separately, just writing out the whole record -- which contains 
an Int as its first attribute.  I was expecting my initial Integer read to pick up this attribute.

But it turns out that Avro Ints 
are written out using  some form of compression (something like zig zag integer
compression from what I can make out.... but this is sort of a side issue to the main
problem).   So, the solution is to explicitly write out the integer BEFORE writing 
the complete Avro record.

Some back ground as to why we need this integer in the first place:

```
The app I am using uses a home grown avro schema management 
approach where schemas are versioned, and the integer code 
tells you which version of the schema to use for deserialization.
```

Here is the revised code:

```
Schema mainSchema =
    SchemaBuilder.record("test").namespace("com.foo").
        fields().
        requiredInt("code").
        requiredString("nickName").
        requiredString("lastName").endRecord();
GenericRecord avroMessage = new GenericData.Record(mainSchema);
avroMessage.put("code", 67);
avroMessage.put("nickName", "robert");
avroMessage.put("lastName", "smith");


ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try (DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(baos)) {
  os.writeInt(1);  // Write out the integer code BEFORE the record
}

Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(baos, null);
DatumWriter<Object> datumWriter = new GenericDatumWriter<>(mainSchema);
datumWriter.write(avroMessage, encoder);
encoder.flush();
baos.close();
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

ByteBuffer wrapped = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
Integer theInt = wrapped.getInt();
byte[] event = new byte[wrapped.remaining()];
wrapped.get(event);

DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(mainSchema);
BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(event, null);
GenericRecord record = reader.read(null, decoder);

System.out.println("theInt:" + theInt);   // should print 67
System.out.println("record:" + record);   // should print:    {"code": 0, "nickName": "", "lastName": ""}
```